# CSS being overwritten

Tags: html, css

I recently installed Teleriks UI Suite for ASP.NET MVC.

Something is overriding my font size from default. Instead of the text being sized normally, the text in most controls shows up this size:

[image]

I would like the text to be default size, maybe around 14 px.

Using Chromes inspect tool along with the "Computed" tool I am able to find out the following information.

"Font-size" is set to 10px, obviously too small.

What is more confusing is that it shows I am referencing mixins.less, which is not even in my project. I have zero references to mixins.less.

[image]

After some research, it appears mixins.less is referenced by the bootstrap.map file, but I have removed the reference to that in my bootstrap.css.

What do I need to modify to alert this text to 14px? Should I attempt to modify bootstrap.css and add some !important tags?

Comment: definitely don't use `!important`. That will make all your fonts 14px, even headers or titles which you may want a bit bigger. It will also force all modifications to use `!important` just to change a font size.

Comment: whatever css style has the most "precise" path to an element will win the battle of styles. Ex. `.main .insidemain div` will style over `.insidemain div`. Try creating more precise style paths than those that are out styling you